# iOS Audio Output Issue: Audio Coming from Front Speaker Instead of Main Speaker

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

**Issue Description:**

I am encountering an issue with audio output on iOS devices when using the YouTube embed feature alongside the user's webcam and audio player on my website. The problem is specifically related to the audio output coming from the front speaker (earpiece) instead of the main speaker on iPhones, including iPhone 12 and 13.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Open the website on an iOS device (iPhone 12, 13, etc.).
2. Start a workout.
3. Observe the audio output location.

**Expected Behavior:**

The audio output should be directed to the main speaker of the device.

**Actual Behavior:**

The audio output is coming out of the front speaker (earpiece).

**Additional Information:**

- This issue is reproducible on multiple iOS devices.
- The website utilizes the YouTube embed feature.
- We also use the user's webcam and play audio during the interaction.

**Environment:**

- iOS devices (iPhone 12, 13, etc.)
- Website URL: [Workout page](https://t.ly/1MiR0)
- Browser: Safari & Chrome on iOS

**Notes:**

When playing a YouTube video on another page where there is no use of a webcam and a separate audio player on the same website, the audio is coming from the main speaker correctly, e.g., on this page: [Videos page](https://t.ly/qSEbj)

Thank you for your assistance in addressing this matter.

Comment: We're not going to be able to pinpoint the problem by looking at the website.  Where is the code that drives the audio from the workouts?